# How to run this script continuously in Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, scheduled-tasks, job-scheduling

I need to run this script in heroku to update my database. The data is retrieve from my facebook post.

I am not sure how to use the Heroku scheduler, what can I do?

```
from facepy import GraphAPI
import json
#import psycopg2
#import mysql.connector

my_token = ....
graph = GraphAPI(my_token)

# Get my latest posts
my_posts = graph.get("me?fields=posts.limit(1){message}", page=False, retry=1, limit=1)

with open('content.json', 'w') as outfile:
  json.dump(my_posts, outfile, indent = 4)

with open('content.json') as data_file:    
    da = json.load(data_file)

a =  da["posts"]["data"][0]["message"]
#fecha = da["posts"]["data"][0]["created_time"]
b=a[0:4]

if b == 'Temp':
    temp = a[5:7]
    hum = a[13:15]
    id = a[20:23]
    print temp
    print hum
    print indent

else:
    print 'error'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Heroku scheduler** is exactly what you are looking for, you can run this code hourly, daily, etc.

They have an excellent tutorial that explains how you turn this code on a rake task and make it run whenever you want: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler